# Canonical question on PXE/"no bootable device" errors, help us close the duplicates

Tags: discussion, questions, canonical-answer

We get variations of what is essentially the same question *all the time*: the system doesn't start Windows, dropping to PXE boot and failing and/or throwing a "no bootable device" or similar error. The answer is the same nearly every time. We ought to collect all these questions and have one question to rule them all.

In the spirit of [this earlier Meta question](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/11820/canonical-question-on-usb-flash-drives-becoming-write-protected/), I've posted [a new canonical question](https://superuser.com/questions/1219285/computer-doesnt-boot-up-shows-pxe-error-and-or-operating-system-not-found) aiming to cover all these cases. I intend to close all other questions of this kind as duplicates of this canonical question. If you have any suggestions on how to go about doing this, be sure to post them here.

Comment: I don't have time to hunt down the dupes, but will happily vote.  Can we create a list of candidates?

Comment: The [list of linked questions](https://superuser.com/questions/linked/1219285) is a good place to start; I've already identified more than two dozen likely duplicates. The [duplicate close vote review queue](https://superuser.com/review/close?filter-closereason=duplicate) is probably even better, since I already voted to close on those likely dupes.

Answer (score 1):

One idea would be to  use a custom SQL query with the [SE Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/queries) tool, and the **Compose Query** option to do the searching part and bring you back a list of links to correlated questions.

[image]

You could search all questions where the title or body contains certain strings or phrases such as: "***the system doesn't start Windows***" "***no bootable device***", etc.

### Custom Query Example

*I didn't write this query for performance or per best practices so it's just give a quick and simple example of **one method** to go about
 helping you with the task of identifying potentially related
 questions to help speed up your process.*

```
SELECT id as [Post Link], *
FROM Posts
WHERE
     (lower(Title) LIKE lower('%##Text##%')) OR
     (lower(Body) LIKE lower('%##Text##%')) AND
     PostTypeId = 1
ORDER BY CreationDate
```

---

### Data Explorer Example

[image]

Comment: The site's built-in search engine is powerful enough to do this easily – there's no need to use SEDE. You can search for whole phrases by enclosing them in double quotes and use parameters like `closed:0` to isolate the search to open questions. It's all documented in the [help center](https://superuser.com/help/searching) and IMHO is one of the most powerful tools in the arsenal for site moderation. (I've used it to shut down massive spam rings in the past.)

Comment: @bwDraco I didn't know about all the functionality packed into the SU search engine with this regard but I'll read up on it when I get some time. I'm curious why you asked a question specifically about *"any suggestions on how to go about doing this"* if you already have a method to do so? Since I'm already very familiar with SQL, I already understand the SEDE interface and how to write queries but I'll learn about the advanced search features of the built-in search engine for sure.

Comment: @bwDraco I also didn't realize you were such a spam hunter and identifier on SU either. I also didn't realize your other views such as politics on your Tweets sir.  I'm a fan; I like your perspective on things and your work here as well Mr. Wo~,

Comment: Thanks :) I've a long history of fighting spam on [SU]. Also, #CaligulaTrump :P